# mac like disk utility for linux

Tags: linux-mint, hfs+

Is there any disk utility like mac for Linux? from where I can create partition (HFS+) based and can copy a dmg image to my usb?

I am using Linux-mint 13, if such utility is available for any other distro I can use that too.

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you're looking for is [Palimpsest Disk Utility](http://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/gnome-disk-utility) (though it's usually only called Disk Utility). You [*should*](http://community.linuxmint.com/idea/view/1487) already have it installed; if not, try installing `gnome-disk-utility`.

[image: GNOME Disk Utility]

(This screenshot lifted from Ubuntu 12.04. Yours will be a bit more green...)

Answer (score 1):

> In Linux and possibly other Unix flavors, most .dmg files can be burned to CD/DVD using the program cdrecord or directly mounted to a mountpoint (e.g. mount -o loop,ro -t hfsplus imagefile.dmg /mnt/mountpoint).
>   – [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Disk_Image)